# Unable to reproduce this figure

Tags: statistics, matlab, density-function

I was looking at an article in which I found this :[image]. I tried to reproduce this figure but I did not find the same thing at all. I am wondering whether this would actually be the contour plot of $\log p(x,y)$. Still, when I plot $\log p(x,y)$ for $-15 \leq x \leq 15$ and $-15 \leq y \leq 15$, I do not have the same figure.

In MATLAB, I used :

```
x=linspace(-15,15);
y=linspace(-15,15);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
myfun = @(X,Y) exp( -X.^2 -Y.^2 - 0.25.*((X.^2 - Y.^2).^2) );
Z=myfun(X,Y);
figure;
contour(X,Y,Z); %not normalized
I=quad2d(@(X,Y) myfun(X,Y),-15,15,-15,15);
figure;
contour(X,Y,Z./I); %normalized
```

What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: I tried the formula with Wolfram and it looks pretty similar, so it is correct. Not a Matlab expert, but probably you need some more precision with contour plot, as I had problems with it also. Or just specify explicitly what contour levels to plot, try $1/e^{10}, 1/e^{20}, 1/e^{30}, \dots$.

Comment: @swish : How did you get something similar with Wolfram Alpha ? I tried and still get something which does not look right. Here is what I asked Wolfram Alpha :
plot( exp( -x^2 -y^2 - 0.25*((x^2 - y^2)^2) ) , x=-15 to 15, y=-15 to 15 )

Comment: Not Alpha, here try it [online](https://lab.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/e6f04dcd-5141-45cc-b4a4-179a2230187d)

Comment: Thanks, with your first comment, I was able to reproduce the figure in Matlab !

Comment: Make the plot like this: `contour(X,Y,Z,myfun(1:6,0))` which forces contours to go through $x=(1,0)$, $x=(2,0)$, $x=(3,0)$, $x=(4,0)$, $x=(5,0)$, and $x=(6,0)$. Yu also need more points in your grid to get smooth contours.